# Memory overhead of objects wrapped by pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm wondering if there is any memory overhead of using C++ classes/structs wrapped by pybind11.
Let's consider a simple example:

```cpp
struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
}

// With some basic bindings
pybind11::class_<Person>(m, "Person")
    .def_readwrite("name", &Person::name)
    .def_readwrite("age", &Person::age);
```

In addition, there is a C++ function that returns millions of persons via a `std::vector<Person>`.
Technically, it is easy to add a pybind11 binding for the function, but is it a good idea to so?

Wrapping the function returns a Python list of person instances.
In general in Python it is inefficient to have a large number of tiny objects, because of memory and GC overheads. The typical solution in Python is to opt for columnar memory layouts, but do these worries apply for classes/structs wrapped by pybind11 as well?

Specifically: If the function returns 1 million elements, will pybind11 internally create another 1 million wrapper instances or do the bindings operate directly on the C++ objects without any overhead? 
Does the type of the members matter?

Answer (score 3):

The `pybind` documentation says that it copies structures every time in binding. That means that these structures and containers are independent in Python and C++, so changes of data in C++ container will not reflect in Python (no references). Also it means that it will duplicate data in C++ and Python - 1 million elements in C++ container and 1 million elements in Python.

See here - https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that is what I was afraid of. Do you have a link to the part in the documentation? I searched for something like that but couldn't find it.